# why sometimes I have to put @Test in the seperate line for it to work in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

The following does not work sometimes

```
 @Test public void testBlah() throws Exception
```

I have to use

```
@Test
public void testBlah() throws Exception
```

I want to know why?

Comment: Depends on what "does not work sometimes" means.  Can you cite an error message?

Answer (score 4):

I guess, because in the former `Test` is not imported, whereas when you press `<enter>` that tends to fix the import automatically without you noticing it, and you get the feeling that it doesn't work on the same line.

I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: If that were true, it should show red in Eclipse as it is not compiled and also throw up a pop-up saying that there are errors in the project when trying to run the test.

Comment: @Paul: Exactly, OP needs to elaborate what "doesn't work" actually means. Otherwise, the behaviour you defined may well precisely mean that that doesn't work.